# how tune twig without whitespaces

Tags: php, symfony, twig

How remove whitespaces within tag in twig? Project writin on Symfony2. In twig's documentation advised to use  {{- value -}}.   I not world want use {%**-** **-**%}, because i have to add this block at each tag. 
if use spaceless, then it remove whitespace between HTML tags, but not delete spaces into a tag.

```
<p>"
             text"</p>
```

Comment: Show us code and what you tried so far

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `spaceless` tag :

```
{% spaceless %}
    <div>
        <strong>foo</strong>
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}

{# output will be <div><strong>foo</strong></div> #}
```

More informations here on the official documentation : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html

Comment: spaceless need for remove spaces between tags. In my case isset whitepsaces inside the tag. On example:                                                                <p>                                                                                                                          "                                                                                                      text "</p>

Comment: Well, that is certainly how it is designed - not to touch anything within the tag itself. It operates only in between tags, as those spaces could introduce margins that are not meant to be....

Answer (score 0):

As @Raphaël suggested, you could use `{% spaceless %}`. Here is an idea to solve that with a single usage:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% spaceless %}
            {% block someBlock %}
            {% endblock %}
        {% endspaceless %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, each template that inherits this one will have spacess removed whatever you put in block named `someblock`.

Hope this helps...

### Edit:

You've got me thinking... you are actually after the `trim()` function, aren't you? If so you could:

```
{{ someDynamicText|trim }}
```

This does not apply to static content as you could easily trim those yourself...

Comment: spaceless not remove spaces into tag. There are tabs and empty line  isset into tag on default

Comment: See the comment I gave on Raphaël's answer ;)